# Access Individual Elements in an Array from an API (react)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

I am a beginner and I am trying to create a recipe app. I managed to set up an API that gives an Array of 10 objects each time I search for a meal like so.

[image: Text]

I access the elements of each recipe using a map

```
{recipes.map(recipe =>(
   <RecipeCard 
   key={recipe.recipe.label}
   title ={recipe.recipe.label} 
   calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
   image={recipe.recipe.image}
   ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
    />
   ))}
```

Here is also my Const Recipe Card just for some more context. It functions fine.

```
    const RecipeCard = ({title, calories, image, ingredients}) => {

        const round = Math.round(calories);
        
        return(
            <div className = {style.recipe}>

                <h1 >{title}</h1>
                <ol className = {style.list}>
                    {ingredients.map(ingredient => (
                        <li>{ingredient.text}</li>
                    ))}
                </ol>
                <p>calories: {round} </p>
                <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/>
                <button>Add to Favorites</button>
      
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I currently only want to access the information from the first array, but whenever I change recipes.map to recipes[0] it says that function does not exist. How should I go about accessing individual elements from the arrays provided from the API?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first array"? There is only one array in your example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.slice(0, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create a **shallow copy** (a new array with just **first** element):

```
{recipes.slice(0, 1).map(recipe =>(
 <RecipeCard 
   key={recipe.recipe.label}
   title ={recipe.recipe.label} 
   calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
   image={recipe.recipe.image}
   ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
  />
))}
```

Or use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const [recipe] = recipes // before "return"

// ....

<RecipeCard 
   key={recipe.recipe.label}
   title ={recipe.recipe.label} 
   calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
   image={recipe.recipe.image}
   ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
/>
```

Or use `index`:

```
<RecipeCard 
   key={recipes[0]?.recipe.label}
   title ={recipes[0]?.recipe.label} 
   calories={recipes[0]?.recipe.calories}
   image={recipes[0]?.recipe.image}
   ingredients={recipes[0]?.recipe.ingredients}
/>
```

The `?.` is called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you can use it to avoid error like *Can't Read property of undefined*, i.e. when the first element is `undefined` and you try to read its properties.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been looking all over google and and youtube and I could not find an answer. I greatly greatly appreciate it.